# Tokenizing string using strtok

Tags: c, strings, memory-management

In this assignment, I'm supposed to split a string using `strtok`. (The assignment consists of the comment and the function definition; I fill in the function body.)

It works as far as I've tested. But it seems a little ugly to me. Perhaps it's my Java background, but somehow this just doesn't feel right. Specific concerns:

- Is this easily readable to a more experienced C programmer?
- Can this be made more idiomatic somewhere?
- Is it feasible to split this into several functions? Where would you split it?
- Any corner cases where it might break? Does it leak memory?

```c
/* Parses a string into tokens (command line parameters) separated by space.
 * Builds a dynamically allocated array of strings. Pointer to the array is
 * stored in variable pointed by argv.
 * 
 * Parameters:
 * argv: pointer to the variable that will store the string array
 * input: the string to be parsed (the original string can be modified, if needed)
 * 
 * Returns:
 * number of space-separated tokens in the string */
int parse_cmdline(char ***argv, char *input)
{
    char *token;
    int len, num;

    len = 4;
    *argv = malloc(len * sizeof(char *));
    if (*argv == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (num = 0;; num++, input = NULL) {
        token = strtok(input, " ");
        if (token == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        if (num >= len) {
            char **temp;

            len *= 2;
            temp = realloc(*argv, len * sizeof(char *));
            if (temp == NULL) {
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    free((*argv)[i]);
                }
                free(*argv);
                *argv = NULL;
                return 0;
            }
            *argv = temp;
        }
        (*argv)[num] = strdup(token);
        if ((*argv)[num] == NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                free((*argv)[i]);
            }
            free(*argv);
            *argv = NULL;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point in tokenizing strings is that

> The number of resulting token would not be known in prior

One good approach is the one you have followed,

- Allocate some memory
- Use it
- Allocate more if needed

I want to answer some of the questions that you have asked.

> Is it feasible to split this into several functions? Where would you
>   split it?

As you see, there is the *repetition* of error handling (freeing up the argv array). Well this can be separated into another function.

> Is this easily readable to a more experienced C programmer?

Not sure of the level of expertise you mean, but I can *read it and understand* without any problems. I am a 2 year experienced C Professional.

> Any corner cases where it might break? Does it leak memory?

There is no obvious memory leak I could see in the program. But you can use tools like *valgrind* to detect such leaks.

I am just posting few code, that I would use, if I am given the same program.

```
int free_argv_q(struct queue *q)
{
    int i;
    int q_len = q_length(q);

    for (i = 0; i < q_len; i++) {
        char *arg = dequeue(q);
        free(arg);
    }

    return 0;
}

int parse_cmdline(char ***argv, char *input)
{
    int i;
    int argc = 0;

    char *arg = NULL;
    char *token = NULL;

    struct queue q;

    token = strtok(input, " ");

    do {
        /* strdup may fail due to low memory */
        arg = strdup(token);

        if (arg == NULL) {
            free_argv_q(&q);
            return 0;
        }

        /* add to queue */
        enqueue(&q, arg);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    } while (token);

    /* length of the queue is the number of splits */
    argc = q_length(&q);

    *argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));

    if (*argv == NULL) {
        free_argv_q(&q);
        return 0;
    }

    /* now we have all memory allocated */
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        argv[i] = dequeue(&q);

    return argc;
}
```

The explanation is as follows.

- I use a **queue** to split the tokens and store them. Well this would grow dynamically.
- After parsing whole input, the `argv` array is allocated
- `argc` is the length of the queue
- Memory allocation failures are handled though
- The cleanup function is separated

**Note:** The implementation of queue is skipped for simplicity. Hope this program is self *explanatory*.